# Bcrypt.compare not executing in chai/mocha tests, but executing in code

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, chai, bcrypt

I have some node.js backend in my project. To encrypt passwords I using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt). To compare string password from requst with hashed password in DB I usin bcrypt.compare function. My bcrypt.compare function works well in code. I tested it manually with Postman and it runs well in production. But in tests with **chai-http** and **mocha** it hangs up.

Test. I use mocha with chai-http to make http POST request:

```
describe('Testing login', () => {
  it('should return status 200 when there is such user in DB and password is correct', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .post('/login')
    .send({
      login: 'test@test.test',
      password: 'somepassword'
    })
    .end((err, res) => {
      res.should.have.status(200)
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Controller bcrypt fucntion looks like that:

```
async function auth (req, res) {
  let { login, password } = req.body
  try {
    let payload = {}
    let result = {}
    await
    User.findOne({ where: { userEmail: login } }).then(user => {      
      return result = user
    })
    bcrypt.compare(password, result.dataValues.password, await function (err, data) {
      if (err) {        
        throw Error(err)
      }
      if (result && data) {       
        payload.isAdmin = result.dataValues.isAdmin
        payload.ID = result.dataValues.id
        let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'yoursecret')
        res.status(200).send({ token: token })
      } else { res.status(401) }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.sendStatus(500)
  }
}
```

Is there any way to test this function?

Additionnal information
mocha version 5.2.0 - global and local
node v8.11.4
windows 10 x64

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.0",
  "chai": "^4.1.2",
  "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
  "chai-http": "^4.2.0",
  "eslint": "^5.5.0",
  "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
  "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
  "express-unit": "^2.1.1",
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
  "mock-express-request": "^0.2.2",
  "mock-express-response": "^0.2.2",
  "nyc": "^13.0.1",
  "proxyquire": "^2.1.0",
  "sinon": "^6.2.0",
  "supertest": "^3.3.0",
  "ws": "3.3.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong behaviour wasn't connected to chai/mocha/bcript. It was caused by following statement

```
    } else {
        res.status(401)
    }
```

correct code should be

```
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(something)
    }
```

or

```
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401)
    }
```

I think Express waiting for .send() after .status() and keep connection without response

Comment: I included this as well in my answer ‍♂️, but a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a few problems, and a few places to look for resources. I do not believe this is a problem with `chai-http`.

[MDN `async/await` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function)
[Using `bcrypt` with Promises.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises)

Here is a rewritten version of your route handler:

```js
async function auth(req, res) {
    let {
        login,
        password
    } = req.body
    try {
        let payload = {}
        let result = await User.findOne({
            where: {
                userEmail: login
            }
        });
        const data = await bcrypt.compare(password, result.dataValues.password);

        if (result && data) {
            payload.isAdmin = result.dataValues.isAdmin
            payload.ID = result.dataValues.id
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'yoursecret')
            res.status(200).send({
                token: token
            })
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you're setting up your routes, but a common mistake is not handling the async functions correctly, [as `express` doesn't do this for you.](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016)

Let me know if this helps. It would also be helpful to see how you are initializing routes and the versions of Node, Express, chai-http, bcrypt, and jsonwebtoken you are using.

Comment: thank you for comment. Routs initialized properly (code works well in production - even previous vervion). I added additional information you asked. I fixed code according to your recomendation - now it much cleaner. But problem is still there. It can easyly be seen by adding multiple console.log to code - bcrypt.compare hangs on without response (when test runs)